# Stuck on proof: If image of gauss map of connected n-surface is single point on the unit n-sphere, S must be a hyper plane

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, tangent-spaces

[image]
The problem is from Thorpe's book *Elementary Topics in Differential Geometry*, where n-surfaces are described in terms of level sets of smooth functions with non-zero gradients on S.

My attempt, and where I am stuck -
Suppose the normal on S at all points is $n$. We need to show that then S is a hyperplane.
Now it is clear that for any point $p$ in S, the tangent space is a hyperplane at $p$ with normal $n$.

So let   $$H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}| (x - p) \cdot n  = 0\}$$

If I can show that for any other point $q$ in S, $q \in H$, then it is proved.

Since S is connected, there exists a continuous function $\alpha: [t_1, t_2] \longrightarrow S$ such that $\alpha(t_1) = p, \alpha(t_2) = q$, and $\alpha(t) \in S \; \forall \; t_1 \leq t \leq t_2$.

I am trying to show that $n\cdot p \neq n \cdot q$ leads to a contradiction. So I assume WLOG that $n \cdot p < n\cdot q$

By the IVT, I know that for every c between $n \cdot p, n\cdot q$, there exists $t$ so that $x = \alpha(t)$ satisfies $n \cdot x = c$.

Now if $$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}| n \cdot p < n\cdot x < n \cdot q \}$$. 
Clearly, $A \subset S$, and I can see $A$ is open in S.

According to the hint in the book, since S now contains an open set $A$, this is a contradiction. 
My question is- what is the contradiction here ?I am unable to close this out.
In one instance, I saw the suggestion that since  S contains an open set, its Gauss map must be the whole n-sphere, but  I do not see how this is either.

Answer (score 1):

This argument is way too complicated, and your claim that $A\subset S$ certainly does not follow; the set $A$ is an $(n+1)$-dimensional region, and $S$ is only an $n$-dimensional hypersurface.

Consider the function $f(x) = (x-p)\cdot n$. Then for any curve $\alpha$ from $p$ to $q$ in $S$, defined on $[t_1,t_2]$ as you had it, we see that
$$(f\circ\alpha)'(t) = \alpha'(t)\cdot n = 0,$$
since $\alpha'(t)$ is in the tangent plane of $S$ at the point $\alpha(t)$. This means the function $f\circ\alpha$ is constant. Thus, $f\circ\alpha(t_2) = f\circ\alpha(t_1)=0$ and so $q\in H$, as well. (We use the fact that $S$ is connected to deduce that we can join $p$ to an arbitrary $q\in S$ by a path lying in $S$.)

**EDIT**: The best sense I can make of Thorpe's attempted argument is this. The reference to the vector field tells us that if any $p\in S$, an open subset of the hyperplane *through* $p$ with normal vector $v$ is contained in $S$. If we have a path $\alpha(t)$ in $S$, $t_1\le t\le t_2$, then this statement applies to every point of that path. For every $y$ value with $\alpha(t_1)\cdot v < y < \alpha(t_2)\cdot v$, we get a piece of a parallel hyperplane through some point $\alpha(t)$ on the curve. The union of these open subsets as we vary $t$ will fill up an open subset of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, all of which is contained in $S$ [That contradicts the implicit function theorem and the fact that a level set must be $n$-dimensional.]. To be sure we actually get an open set here requires some analysis/topology, unless that differential equations result gives us existence for a uniform $\epsilon$ time independent of where we start.

Comment: I posted the question as posed in the book. Is the hint there wrong, because I was trying to follow it and see where it led.

Comment: That is a crazy proof. Proof by contradiction is totally unnecessary. The proof I've given is far more direct. I don't know what $U$ is in which you pasted. And what is the theorem regarding vector fields to which they refer? As it stands, their argument looks wrong. The contradiction is supposed to be then that $S$ contains an open subset of an open ball in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$? But that does not follow from the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The $U$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ on which the smooth function that defines $S$ as a level set is defined. I have been struggling with this hint for the past few days, and it seemed to make sense intuitively, but obviously I could not finish the argument.  The first part shows that S contains, locally, all its tangent planes. Thus the contradiction seems to me to be that the surface has "thickness" (all the hyperplanes in the set defined by the IVT. But I could not see how to conclude.

Comment: It certainly doesn't follow from what is there. What is that reference to vector fields about? ... Sometimes it's best to ignore hints and figure out your own (easy) proof.

Comment: The reference to the earlier theorem is that for a tangent vector field (in this case constant field) at point p on S, one can get a maximal integral curve a(t) = tw + p in the neighbourhood of p such that a(0) = p, and a(t) in S.

Comment: OK, so by choosing the vector field to be anything orthogonal to $v$, he deduces that an open neighborhood of $p$ in $H$ is contained in $S$. Now he wants you to extend that argument to show that if we have a curve in $B\cap S$ along which $x\cdot v$ varies, then we can take parallel planes to $H$ through those points and generate a whole open subset of $B$ that must be contained in $S$, contradicting the implicit function theorem that $S$ is $n$-dimensional. This is an insanely complicated argument and I cannot imagine why he's being so stubborn as to sketch that.

Comment: I should make the point (see *my* free differential geometry text, linked in my profile) that using derivative equal to 0 to show a function (on a connected domain) is constant proves countless results in differential geometry. It's important to apply that result from calculus without getting buried in spurious applications of proof by contradiction and the IVT.

Comment: I understand your original argument  for this. I have worked through the first 6 chapters of your Multivariable Calculus book too. However, I try to follow an authors viewpoint, believing he/she must be doing it for a reason. Could you add the contradiction proof at the end as an answer, I shall mark this closed then.

Comment: Assuming that it is not a suprious proof, that is.